# Mixed content - SSL http/https issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

Approximately 2 months ago I installed a SSL certificate on my site, catherinerushforth.com. I changed the site and WordPress URL in the admin area of WordPress to include https:// instead of http://. All was fine.

Then, about 2 weeks ago I started to have a problem with "Mixed Content" errors on all pages except the main home page. There doesn't seem to be an issue when viewing the site with Safari but there is a problem with Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. I inspected the Javascript console in Chrome (as an example) and saw multiple "Mixed Content" errors

This is what I have do so far to try and fix these mixed content errors:

1. Changed http:// to https:// in the WordPress Admin section for the site and WordPress URLs (Settings/General)
2. I've added "define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);" to the top of the wp-config.php file.
3. I've added the following piece of code to the .htaccess file:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^catherinerushforth.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://catherinerushforth.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   ```

   With this code I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
4. I've also tried the plugin, WordPress HTTPS (SSL).

None of the above have worked.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and/or have any suggestions as to how I can fixed this issue?

Many thanks.

**WordPress version: 4.2.2
Theme: X-theme v.4 (although issue was the same in previous version of this theme)
Site: catherinerushforth.com**

**UPDATE**
If I simply remade each page for my site (which I will probably have to do at some point due to X-Theme now using their CornerStone page builder) would this ensure all links were https:// and not http://?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37903102/3599237

Answer (score 2):

Remove

`define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`

from wp-config.php, be sure you have changed `http://` to `https://` in WordPress Admin, and then force SSL for front and backends with this in .htaccess *above* the WordPress rewrite block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://catherinerushforth.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That only forces SSL; you still need to find the site resources which are loading non-SSL.

So use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the errors with specific site resources.

**And:**

• you should change URLs of media items and links in the post/page content to https so they don't depend on the redirect in .htaccess. [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace (optionally with grep) through all posts, pages, excerpts, comments, titles and meta. And, [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) can be used to find/replace in the entire database, i.e. metadata, GUIDs and widget content, etc.

• You may need to change to a relative path for images in CSS files, i.e. `background-image: url(http://example.com/themes/wp-content/theme/images/image.jpg)` to `background-image: url(images/image.jpg)`

• You may need to remove the `http` from absolute paths in php theme files, i.e. change `'http://example.com/image.jpg'` to `'//example.com/image.jpg'`; that will allow your resources to default to https.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Just to make sure I follow your steps precisely, do I add the "RewriteEngine On..." code, you've supplied above, within the WordPress default code "# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" code or between its own "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>....</IfModule> in the .htaccess?

Comment: Add it above the # BEGIN WordPress block; it has to be executed before the WordPress rules. You shoudn't need the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>..., but depending on your host, you may need to add it.

Comment: Thanks Mark for clearly explaining where to put that code. Unfortunately now every link on the site directs to the home page, catherinerushforth.com. I've tried with and without the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>....</IfModule> bit.

Comment: Then remove it. Be sure you have changed http:// to https:// in WordPress Admin. Use Dev Tools to find inseure elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

[Source](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteSSL)

Comment: Thank you Lars for your quick response and advice.  I'm getting a redirect error with this code. Perhaps though it's something related to another thing I've done, as above in my initial question. Do I have to replace "server name" and/or "request_uri" with site specific text?

Comment: No, these are [variables](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html)

Comment: That will not prevent the initial connection to be made over plain HTTP (before the redirection happens), so the mixed content error will remain.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this issue on image urls being returned as `http://https://website.com/image.jpg`. What I did was use the Velvet URL plugin to rewrite the urls for all content from `http://https://websiteurl` to `https://websiteurl`. This fixed the issue for me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu 16.04, letsencrypt, nginx, apache2, wordpress. For me

```
1. adding redirect in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` didn't work (too many redirects)

2. adding RewriteRule in .htaccess didn't work (too many redirects)
```

Finally I installed really-simple-ssl plugin from wordpress and it worked like charm.