# WordPress with SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I've tried to set WordPress Address and Site Address with `https://` but still showing up with mixed content and every link is blocked by browser.
These mixed contents are every css and js files of wordpress.

I'm using a S3 Bucket as CDN, BeanStalk to server, and CloudFront to serve my webpage.

This is the link used to build this system, and fails at the moment the author set the WordPress Address and Site Address: [Deploying WordPress
with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37903102/3599237

Answer (score 2):

Have you made any setting changes in your wp-config.php file? This is my setup (added wp-config.php) to run a https site:

```
// Work out if we are using https
$isSecure = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    $isSecure = true;
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
    $isSecure = true;
}
$REQUEST_PROTOCOL = $isSecure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', $REQUEST_PROTOCOL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-content');
define( 'WP_HOME', $REQUEST_PROTOCOL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Comment: Also make sure all your css and js is enqued correctly wp_enqueue_style etc... using the above code will make sure it is referenced as https.