# Mixed content warning but nothing in source

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mixed-content

My client has a Wordpress site with an SSL certificate. Riht now I'm trying to figure out any solution.

The site address is https://illustro.pl
When entered on the front page you'll get the un secure connection warning. 
I've tried to find what causes this with any luck, solutions that have not worked

- replace http with https
- change all http to https with [Mixed Content/Insecure Content SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650396/mixed-content-insecure-content-ssl/37903102#37903102)

In the process I've also changed all the URLs to HTTPS in the database on sites where the was the need to.

I'iv inspected the site with multiple developers tools all of them show the problem at line one.

At this point any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code placing at wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multible reasons:

Main reason is currently that your webserver is not sending the full certificate chain (intermediate certificate is missing). That's the current reason why the browser tells you "unknown issuer".

The next reason could be or will be that your certificate doesn't have subject alternative names. Browsers will stop checking for common name in future.

Comment: I've checked and reinstalled the certificate including the intermediate one, how long till the error should disappear?

Comment: Immediately after (web)server restart/reload